# when compiling the code into apk the pictures wont display

Tags: android

when compiling the code into apk the pictures wont display on android studio but there is no error. texts field are just fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_maint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/jpg"
     >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="MY SOCIAL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="133dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/faceboooook"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="133dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitter"
                android:id="@+id/imageView95"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="133dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rosinsta"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        ...
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ross"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/about"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/contacts"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/exit"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when compiling the code into apk the pictures wont display .thats android studio

Comment: Removed some of the irrelevant XML and reformatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you set your image in LinearLayout..!!